# How to make a Form Action work with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My action function is not working.  I am not sure if I missed something in my syntax. or you have to call it as a function in a different way.  I am trying to put the form action in with JQuery instead of through the form to make sure that when it is done it goes back to the main page it called this from.

The old Code would load the form and give the user a blank screen instead of staying on the current page.

Old Code:

```
<form id="import_audit_form" name="import_audit_form" action='./edit_audits.php?action=process_import' method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

New Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#audit_submit').click(function(){

        $('#import_audit_form').attr('action', 'edit_audits.php?action=process_import',{
            function(data){
            alert("Audit Imported");

            }); //end import_audit_form
    }); // End audit_submit

}); //End document function
</script>

<form id="import_audit_form" name="import_audit_form" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" name="audit_submit" id="audit_submit" value="TRANSFER" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery `.attr` receives one (as getter) or two (as setter) arguments. It is unclear what the third argument does there.

Comment: I just wanted to verify that the information when through like with a $.post command $.post("./edit_audits.php?action=process_import",{
    function(data){alert("Audit Imported");
    }

Comment: Why not keep the action so that it works without JavaScript enabled? Then just extract the action with `.attr` and use that as the url to `POST` to.

Comment: So I guess I would only have this option?  $('#import_audit_form').attr('action', 'edit_audits.php?action=process_import');
   alert("Audit Button Pressed Success");

Comment: try submitting form through  $("#formId").submit();